Systemd-user-service to enable keyboard gives no error but doesn't work
I have a bad laptop keyboard and a much better Lily58, so I wrote a bash-script to be able to disable my laptop keyboard so I can place the Lily58 on it and re-enable it after. But when I disable the laptop keyboard, it stays disabled if I put the laptop in suspension while I would prefer it to be automatically re-enabled on resume. So I wrote a short bash script
#!/bin/bash

fconfig="/home/alex/.keyboard" 
id=$(xinput | grep AT | sed -n '2,2p' | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')

if [ -f $fconfig ]; then
  read -r var< $fconfig
  if [ "$var" = "disabled" ]; then
      xinput enable $id
      echo "enabled" > $fconfig
  fi
fi

This checks whether "disabled" is in the file /home/alex/.keyboard that tracks whether the keyboard is enabled, and if so runs xinput to re-enable using the id it got by sifting through the output of xinput  in the manner used in the definition of id, then set /home/alex/.keyboard to enabled. This works as it should when I trigger the bash-script from the terminal, but when I start the systemd-service
[Unit]
Description=This service enables your keyboard after suspension
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/alex/bash/enable-keyboard

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

that I want to run after suspend, it sets /home/alex/.keyboard to enabled but does not actually re-enable my keyboard. Moreover, journalctl -xeu enable-keyboard.service indicates no error:
Jul 17 22:16:25 gentoolaptop systemd[795]: Starting This service enables your keyboard after suspension.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://gentoo.org/support/
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 8969.
Jul 17 22:16:25 gentoolaptop systemd[795]: Finished This service enables your keyboard after suspension.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://gentoo.org/support/
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 8969.

What is going wrong?
Edit: If I put a clause into the script to print the output of xinput into a file, the output consists of one empty line.
Edit: the output of systemctl --user status dbus.socket dbus.service is
● dbus.socket - D-Bus User Message Bus Socket
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/dbus.socket; static)
                Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-07-18 17:22:54 CEST; 5 days ago
                Triggers: ● dbus.service
                Listen: /run/user/1000/bus (Stream)
                Tasks: 0 (limit: 47295)
                Memory: 4.0K (peak: 1.5M)
                CPU: 8ms
                CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/dbus.socket

                Jul 18 17:22:54 gentoolaptop systemd[830]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
                Jul 18 17:22:54 gentoolaptop systemd[830]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.

                ● dbus.service - D-Bus User Message Bus
                Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/dbus.service; static)
                                Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-07-18 17:22:54 CEST; 5 days ago
                                TriggeredBy: ● dbus.socket
                                Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
                                Main PID: 897 (dbus-daemon)
                                Tasks: 1 (limit: 47295)
                                Memory: 1.0M (peak: 1.7M)
                                CPU: 252ms
                                CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/dbus.service
                                └─897 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only

                                Jul 23 16:55:45 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' unit='dunst.service' requested by ':1.149' (uid=1000 pid=105378 comm="/bin/dunstify Battery <80 Battery under 80%.")
                                Jul 23 17:11:00 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
                                Jul 23 17:19:31 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' unit='dunst.service' requested by ':1.152' (uid=1000 pid=106706 comm="/bin/dunstify Battery <80 Battery under 80%.")
                                Jul 23 17:21:31 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
                                Jul 23 17:30:31 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' unit='dunst.service' requested by ':1.153' (uid=1000 pid=108520 comm="/bin/dunstify Battery <80 Battery under 80%.")
                                Jul 23 17:32:31 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
                                Jul 24 14:15:05 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' unit='dunst.service' requested by ':1.164' (uid=1000 pid=126615 comm="/bin/dunstify Battery <80 Battery under 80%.")
                                Jul 24 14:17:05 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
                                Jul 24 14:26:05 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' unit='dunst.service' requested by ':1.165' (uid=1000 pid=127823 comm="/bin/dunstify Battery <80 Battery under 80%.")
                                Jul 24 14:28:05 gentoolaptop dbus-daemon[897]: [session uid=1000 pid=897 pidfd=5] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)

The output of ls -l /run/user/*/bus is
srw-rw-rw-   1 alex           alex            0 2024-07-18 17:22 /run/user/1000/bus
```.


Have you tried to put your script as executeable into /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep and check first parameter $1 for "pre"  (before the system suspends) and "post" (after the system wakes from suspend). When it works in terminal, it must work in post, after the system wakes up, hm....

@Schmaehgrunza No, I'm not even at the point where I can worry about it working after suspend, the service doesn't re-enable the keyboard even if I start it manually. I tested now what the output is when I call xinput through the service, and it seems it doesn't produce any output whatsoever, even though the variables corresponding to my X session should be set since I'm calling the service as part of graphical-session.target.

the point is, if you put it there you dont need a service unit, just a simple executable script. If you want a service unit try
WantedBy=graphical-session.target```   ---> ```sudo systemctl daemon-reload; sudo systemctl disable ...service; sudo systemctl enable ....service```

@Schmaehgrunza Ah, I see. But I don't think that it would work if I put it as a script there if it doesn't when I start it as a service. It seems that systemd just doesn't obtain any output from xinput for some reason. I also changed the WantedBy to graphical-session.target and did daemon-roload, but it still doesn't work.

Note: This answer assumes that the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY environment variable would be imported to the systemd user manager by your desktop environment, and that you always log in with the same user account.
xinput is an X utility. In other words, it is an X client. Therefore, you will need to denote which X server it should to talk to (even if there is just one running) with the DISPLAY environment variable, and allow it to connect to it with the XAUTHORITY environment.
The tricky thing is, it doesn't seem like there's a neat way to make the user manager(s) of the logged in user(s) to pull in user service upon system sleep (and resume). Also, technically you can have multiple user logged in and multiple X server running, so somewhat there is really no way to "improve" how things work for scenario like this, at least not without relying on some dirty assumptions.
With that said, you can still "hardcode" a solution as long as you are fine with those assumptions:
[Unit]
Description=This service enables your keyboard after suspension
PartOf=sleep.target
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/runuser alex -c 'systemd-run --user /home/alex/bash/enable-keyboard'

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target

systemd-run --user is made possible in the system service with runuser, so do not replace it with User=. Also, do not use it as a user service.

EDIT: Since it seems that somehow your runuser does not work as expected, you may want to try the following version  instead:
[Unit]
Description=This service enables your keyboard after suspension
PartOf=sleep.target
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=alex
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
ExecStart=/usr/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/systemd-run --user /home/alex/bash/enable-keyboard

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target

Make sure your ~/.xinitrc consists of at least a line that source /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh (assuming the file exists in your system) before the exec line:
. /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh


With the service enabled, the script should be called each time after system resume (which is when sleep.target would be stopped, hence the PartOf= and ExecStop=).
P.S. You may even just hardcode DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY inside your script (export). In that case ExecStop=/home/alex/bash/enable-keyboard should work.

If you also need /home/alex/bash/enable-keyboard to be run upon graphical login, write another service for it (this time it should probably be a user service instead):
[Unit]
Description=This service enables your keyboard after suspension
After=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/alex/bash/enable-keyboard

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target

Make sure you enable this service with systemctl --user. Also it would work only if your desktop environment would actually get graphical-session.target pulled in upon graphical login.
(NOTE: when you use startx, very likely the target would not get pulled in. You should either just call (not source, even though it might be alright for it) your script in ~/.xinitrc before the exec line, or if you really want the user manager to call it, use systemctl --user to start the target or the service in your ~/.xinitrc (again, before the exec line).)
The reason that it cannot be a system service is, assuming the script needs to be run after the X server in the user session is started, you would need to poll in the script (or abuse Restart=) and wait until then. (But of course, there's a chance that you can just make it talk to the X server of the display manager, if there is one, and that the effect will retain. But then you will need to find out and hardcode the corresponding DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY, and depending on how the display manager "interact" with systemd, it may be doomed to be "racy" and you will need to have some nasty "sleep 5" whatsoever.)
You may even instead just call the script with an xinitrc.d script, XDG autostart, or whatever works under your DE.

So I created the service you wrote but when I start it, it doesn't enable my keyboard. I also tried setting DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY in the script, but while the script still works when I run it manually, it still doesn't work when I use systemd to start it. I guess DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY aren't the problem? Maybe some other variable? The service log says Failed to connect to bus: No medium found

@AlexanderPraehauser Does executing systemd-run --user /home/alex/bash/enable-keyboard in a terminal give you the same error?

@AlexanderPraehauser As I stated in my answer, if you hard code DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY in your script, then you don't need runuser and systemd-run --user in ExecStop=. In your use case, the point of runuser is pretty much just setting an env var for systemd-run --user, of which the point is setting env vars for xinput. AFAIK, the error you saw indicates something related to systemd/dbus/login session is broken. (It could either be some bug/flaw in certain versions of related programs/libraries, or just that your installation has been messed up somehow.)

@AlexanderPraehauser Btw, what do you see if run sudo runuser alex -c printenv | grep run/ in a terminal?

@Tom_Yan The systemd-command does not give an error when I execute it as my normal user (but also doesn't activate my keyboard) but does give that error if I exectue it as sudo (which I guess it should). If I run the runuser command I get no output whatsoever. I'm using startx to start my graphical session, could that have something to do with it? The command I'm using in my xinitrc is exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session /home/alex/.stumpwm.d/stumpwm.ros 

@AlexanderPraehauser Well, if you use startx, you need a script in the xinitrc.d directory to get DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY imported (if you want leverage systemd-run --user), but such a script is shipped by systemd these days /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh. But the real problem you are having is, apparently you don't get the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in the at least the session runuser started. (Or maybe runuser in your distro does not start a session? I don't know.)

@AlexanderPraehauser Do you see any of the two env vars I just mentioned in systemctl --user show-environment (no sudo)? I'm not sure why you need dbus-launch in your xinitrc either. Maybe add the output of systemctl --user status dbus.socket dbus.service (and maybe ls -l /run/user/*/bus too) to your question.

systemctl --user show-environment shows neither DISPLAY nor XAUTHORITY. I added the output of the other two commands to my question.

I was really referring to XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS. And to get DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY imported, make sure /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh exists and is sourced in your ~/.xinitrc (before the exec line).

Ah, those two are shown by show-environment. /50-systemd-user.sh exists, but it wasn't sourced by my .xinitrc. I put in a line. Do you think it will work if restart the X session now?

Well, because If I run the runuser command I get no output whatsoever (assuming you mean sudo runuser alex -c printenv | grep run/ run in a terminal), so maybe use the version of service file in my edit. Restart X and check systemctl --user show-environment again, if DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY are there, edit the service and and run systemctl daemon-reload. Make sure it is correctly enabled (symlinked in /etc/systemd/system/sleep.target.wants), then try a sleep-resume cycle and see.

It seems to have worked! Now also my other services needing dbus seem to be able to communicate. Many thanks, I had no idea I should have put that line into my .xinitrc!

You are right, xinput produces no output. I've tested this.System Service units run outside of the scope/environment of Xorg.
You have to put your unit in /usr/lib/systemd/user/myservice.service, then you have full access.
What i tried. Created a service myservice.service in /usr/lib/systemd/user or better in /home/[username]/.config/systemd/user
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=absolute path to service script

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target

my service script:
#!/usr/bin/bash
while :; do
   if [[ -a "/tmp/suspension_wakeup" ]]; then
      wake_up=$(< /tmp/suspension_wakeup);
      if [[ $wake_up == "true" ]]; then
         echo "$(xinput)" > /tmp/xinput
         echo "false" > /tmp/suspension_wakeup
      fi
   fi
   sleep 10
done

I'm reading from a file in tmp folder called suspension_wakeup.
If suspension_wakeup contains "true", then echo xinput to a file in tmp folder called xinput. Here you can add your code, instead of echoing.
then write false to suspension_wakeup.
I'll put another file called suspension_wakeup (executable script) in /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
#!/usr/bin/bash
[[ $1 == "post" ]] && { umask 0111; echo "true" > /tmp/suspension_wakeup; }

this script writes "true" in the suspension_wakeup file in tmp folder.
That causes the service unit to echo the xinput or do your stuff, if you insert that.
the service is enabled with:
systemctl --user enable myservice.service
and started with
systemctl --user start myservice.service
you have to put "--user" after "systemctl" for each systemctl command
That worked, everytime the computer goes to sleep and wake up.
Better would be to let the script in /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleepchange the keyboard. But i tried and tried with no solution.
Perhaps you have an idea? Let me know, if you got it.

So I did exactly as you said, I copied the script you wrote and created a user systemd unit with the same contents, but when I start the systemd service or enable it, suspend and wake up, the script creates /tmp/xinput but it is an empty file. But it works for you? It shows you all connected devices?

Yes it works, it shows all connected devices. https://superuser.com/questions/759759/writing-a-service-that-depends-on-xorg,  In this thread, they are talking about that this only works in Debian Archlinux Ubuntu. Im on Linux Mint, its based on ubuntu.

Hmm. Gentoo is pretty different from all of those, and in particular its support for systemd isn't the strongest (the more native init system is openrc). Maybe they didn't do some configuration the other distros did.
